# Python code for defining a function to find 1st last and medium of given list

Tags: python, list, indexing, slice

I have a task to write a code to find 1st medium and last element of a list. If list lenght is 1 the function must return as the 1st medium and last element as the unique element of the list. If list's length is even the medium element is the ((n/2) – 1) position of the list

So if 
mylist = ['Nick', 5.8, 107, ['knife', 'gun']]
 (even length)
1st = Nick , medium = 5.8, last = ['knife', 'gun'] 
If
mylist = ['Nick', 5.8, 107, ['knife', 'gun'], 12]
 (odd length) 
1st = Nick , medium = 107, last = 12

I have started to write the following code. In if...else have 2 alternatives to find the result

But as I try it get the following error

```
File "main.py", line 3
    if len(mylist) == 1
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing?

Here is my try

```
mylist = ['Nick', 5.8, 107, ['knife', 'gun']]
def FML(mylist): ## definition of First Medium Last function (FML)
    if len(mylist) == 1:
        res = [ mylist[0], mylist[0], mylist[0]]
        print ("The first, last and the medium element of list are : " + str(res))
    else:
        if (len(mylist) % 2) == 0 # list size even
            res = [ mylist[0], mylist[-1], mylist[int((len(mylist)/2) - 1)] ] # list slicing
            print ("The first, last and the medium element of list are : " + str(res))
        else: # list size odd
            res = [ mylist[0], mylist[-1], mylist[int(len(mylist)/2) ] ]  # list slicing
            print ("The first, last and the medium element of list are : " + str(res))
```

Upadted my try with the missing (:)

Comment: you're missing a `:` at the end of your conditional statements to address your error

Comment: Dirty text and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your code. Even when the length of the list is 1, index -1 returns the last value which is the same as the first value. I also incorporated integer division(`//`) in your code to clean up the other if-else statement.

```
def FML(mylist):
    res = [mylist[0], mylist[len(mylist)//2], mylist[-1]]
    print("The first, last and the medium element of list are : " + str(res))
```

The original problem with your code, however, was due do a missing colon on the lone with the if condition.